# How to override DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain by our own implementaion of credential provider with assume role

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to  use spring config server with cross account as I am deploying config server in kubernetise with aws backed.
but due to DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain I am unable to get connected to s3 bucket and gets 403 error.

In DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain  as per logs WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider try to  get credentials get 403 error.

but when I am try to connect with my awss3 client with STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider it gets connect.

Is there any way so that I can provide STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider instead of DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain